# ¿Cómo conseguir que se vea en una TextView los valores de una variable que está en un blucle, con Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

estoy intentando que se visualicen todos los valores de mi base de datos pero solo consigo que en el TextView se vea el último valor. Esta es una parte del código:

```
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()){
 var jsonObject = jsonArray[i]
 var text = jsonObject.toString();
 println(text)
 tvResultado.text = jsonObject.toString()
 Toast.makeText(applicationContext,text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

En el Toast y en el println sí que se ven todos los valores pero en la pantalla de la app no.

Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es el siguiente:

Estas realizando un bucle que constantemente modifica el valor de tvResultado utilizando .text, es decir, al terminar el bucle solo tienes el ultimo valor.

Para conseguir lo que tu quieres, tienes que concatenar los distintos textos de la siguiente manera:

```
tvResultado.text = tvResultado.text.toString() + text
```

Espero que esto sea lo que andas buscando.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Sí que funciona, de corazón gracias.